# Haskell Operator Interpretation

Tags: haskell, syntax

I have come across the following in Haskell: `foldl (&&) True [False | _ <- [1..]]`. I know what the `foldl` function does and that this expression involves infinite recursion, but what does this expression actually mean? I am mainly unsure of what `|` and `<-` do in this context.

Comment: That's a [list comprehension](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension)

Comment: Where did you see that? It's just a long, complicated way of writing `False`, since the first application of `&&` will produce a `False` value that will prevent `foldl` from needing to read the rest of the (infinite) list (because `False && _ == False`). Worse, it never terminates, since `foldl` has to start from the "end" of the infinite list.

Comment: Note that in programming, it is important to break down an expression like this into it's relevant pieces. This is called parsing. In this case, `|` and `<-` by themselves are not very meaningful. Instead, you must look at the arguments to `foldl` as explained in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the `foldl` function applied to three arguments:

1. `(&&)`
2. `True`
3. `[False | _ <- [1..]]`

The third argument is a list defined by a list comprehension. It is simply an infinite sequence of `False` values: the list is built with a `False` value for each value of `_` pulled from the infinite sequence 1, 2, 3, .... It could more simply be defined as `repeat False`:

```
foldl (&&) True (repeat False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read [the haskell wiki about list-comprehension](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension).

This: `[ expr | expr <- expr ]` is a syntax called list-comprehension.

`_` means ignore this variable, and `|` is used to separate the left and the right part of the list-comprehension expression.

Answer (score 1):

The foldl operator accumulates values by iterating over a list and calling a binary operator on the accumulator and the current place in the list.

I.e. (&&) means we are using the AND operator to accumulate on the value TRUE.

Now for the final part. This is a list comprehension. It is similar to set notation you might have seen in math classes. Basically we are defining a list, the | means such that and the _ <- [1..] means we are loading each value from 1 to infinity, but since we are loading it into _, it's being ignored. This defines an infinite list of False, so on the first fold we will return false because True && False is always False.

I think this is the same as the function all.

Comment: It is the same as `Prelude.and` (not `all`) for finite input lists, but for an infinite list containing at least one `False`, `and` will return `False`, where this version using `foldl` will never return.